# jquerytools tooltip with content from an AJAX call?

Tags: tooltip, jquery-tools

We are using `jquerytools` and want to use the `tooltip` functionality for showing content
loaded through `AJAX`.

The documentation of `jquerytools tooltip` say that the content of the `tooltip` must be contained within the `HTML` directly after the element that should receive
the `tooltip`.

Is there no better way? The UI is too complex and this requirement sux.

how would you implement a `jquerytools tooltip` functionality with `tooltip` content sucked in through `AJAX`?

Answer (score 2):

I am using a customized version of tiptip:

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

however, why can't you just use ajax to dynamically insert an element after for tooltip content?

you can have a "template" div somewhere like so:

```
<div id="tooltip-template" style="display:none"><span></span>...</div>
```

and inside your callback:

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:    '...',
    type:   "POST",
    data:   JSON.stringify(...),
    success: function(result)
    {
       var tooltip = $("#tooltip-template").clone( );

       tooltip.find("span").html(result.name);

       var target = $("#tooltip-target");

       target.after(tooltip);

       target.tooltip( );
    }
});
```